# Why click is not working when i'm using nested click for input type file design customization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have input type file this click is working file when its default design, but when i try to customize it with another button this is not working.

My Code:-

```js
  $('button').click(function () {
    $('[name=photo_input]').change(function (e) {
            var imagePath = e.target.files[0].name;
        });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Select Photo</button>
<input type="file" name="photo_input" style="display:none;">
```

Thank You!

Comment: $('[name=photo_input]').trigger('click'); you need to trigger under the button click.

Comment: I know its will work fine but i can't use just trigger('click'), I have to click with function like given in my question

Comment: `$('button').click(function () {
    $('[name=photo_input]').click().change(function (e) {
            alert(e.target.files[0].name);
        });
   });`

Comment: @Ritesh Khandekar Thank you so much its working fine.

Comment: @RohitVerma HTML already have same behaviour by default [`label Tag`](https://jsfiddle.net/vgbrm2jw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need to trigger the event inside the button click.
for more on [trigger API](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```js
$('button').on('click',function () {
      debugger;
        $('[name=photo_input]').trigger('click');
   });
   
   $('[name=photo_input]').change(function (e) {
            var imagePath = e.target.files[0].name;
            alert(imagePath);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Select Photo</button>
<input type="file" name="photo_input" style="display:none;">
```